# jQuery code into angularjs controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

So I got this code in a script tag that works:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#tableOS').excelTableFilter();
  });
</script>
```

I want to execute that jQuery function inside a $timeout in angularJS Controller like in this method:

```
var loadServiceOrders = function(){

    OrdemServicoFactory.getOrdemServico(token).success(function(resposta){
        $timeout(function() {
          //execute what's inside that script tag here
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: developers... he's new user, please flag question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it as angular directive

```
app.directive("tab", function(){
  return {
     link: function(scope, element){
       element.excelTableFilter();
     }
  }
})


<div id="tableOS" tab>....</div>
```

so if we want to run this `directive` after some function or anything we should bind listener for example:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $http){
     $http.get("orders").success(function(data) {
         $scope.data = data;
         //we get the data so we need to run directive
         $scope.runDirective = data.length > 0 ? true : false;
     })
})
```

**update directive:**

```
app.directive("tab", function(){
  return {
     scope: {
       tab: "="
     },
     link: function(scope, element){
       scope.$watch("tab", function(newValue) {
         if(newValue){
            element.excelTableFilter();
         }
       })
     }
  }
})
```

**update view**

```
<div id="tableOS" tab="runDirective">....</div>
```

so with this model you can run directive after get data from controller.

please, Fill free to ask question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to execute that function after I get a response array, after the $timeout and I can't execute a directive inside the $timeout can I?

Comment: Ok my friend, let make it happen i suggest to you to improve question by add more code and explain more about your target, it's make you to get more and best answers

Comment: Thanks, I just improved my question. Hope it is ok now :)

Comment: me too improve the answer :)

Comment: For some reason I debugged it and is not entering the jQuery method \: